# How to pass multiple filenames to ImageMagick?

Tags: windows, command-line, imagemagick

To average together multiple images, globbing works fine:

```
magick convert -average *.png out.png
```

But how would I specify several input images on Windows command line, without using globbing?  (Ultimate goal is to make a batch file so I can select multiple images, then combine them using SendTo menu, for which `%*` will receive `"C:\...filename.png" "C:\...file2.png" "C:\...something.png"`.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several options...

---

#### Option 1

You can just enumerate  the files on the command line:

```
magick fred.png bill.png tina.png -average result.png
```

I haven't tried this, but from your question, the following should work as it is directly equivalent to the example above:

```
magick %* -average result.png
```

---

#### Option 2

You can write the filenames in a file and pass its name, so if `filelist.txt` contains:

```
image1.png
image2.png
image3.png
```

Then run:

```
magick @filelist.txt -average result.png
```

---

#### Option 3

You can send the list of filenames to **ImageMagick** on its `stdin`:

```
echo -e "file1.png\nfile2.png\file3.png" | magick @- -average result.png
```

Not sure how you do a newline in BATCH - but the `\n` above are newlines!

Maybe it is:

```
( echo file1.png & echo file2.png & echo file3.png ) | magick @- -average result.png
```

---

The `convert` is actually implicitly assumed since v7 - you only need specify the legacy command if you do `magick identify ...` or `magick mogrify ...` or `magick compose ...` etc.

Comment: The `convert` is actually implicitly assumed since v7 - you only need specify the legacy command if you do `magick identify ...` or `magick mogrify ...` or `magick compose ...` etc.

Comment: I recommend using the newer -evaluate-sequence mean rather than -average, which may become fully deprecated at some later time in IM 7. See http://imagemagick.org/script/porting.php#cli

Answer (score 1):

In Powershell, `@` needs to be escaped, and you can replace `'@files.txt'` with `'@-'` if you want to pipe args in:

```
magick -dispose Previous -delay 0 '@files.txt' output.apng
```

If you need to prepare a list of files,

```
gci -name *.png | out-file .\files.txt
```

or simply do it all in one line:

```
gci -name *.png | magick -dispose Previous -delay 0 '@-' output.apng
```

The order of arguments in Image Magick is important, and this is what worked for me as of Image Magick 7.1.

Comment: Useful info, though I had some trouble getting this to work with `'@files.txt'` syntax. It kept giving a `: unable to open image '.` error. I eventually got it working with `cat files.txt | magick ... '@-'` instead